# hdfs URI is not resolved

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-checkpoint

In my curresnt spark application I am checkpointing to hdfs and the hdfs URI is like below

```
hdfs:///tmp/log
```

I am getting an error  `org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: Uri without authority: hdfs:/tmp/`

I am observing that `///` is resolved to `/`.

Is this a bug or am I missing any configuration.
 Thank you

Comment: what is your question? the error is because the processiing user doesn't have authority to `hdfs:/tmp/` and regarding your second query both `hdfs:///tmp/log` and `hdfs:/tmp/log` are same

Comment: when I pass the path as hdfs://nameNode/tmp/log I am not seeing the error and the executing user has all the previlages to the hdfs path.

Comment: An "authority" is part of the URI definition, not permissions

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configure the `fs.defaultFS` in the `core-site.xml` file. (spark:3.2.0, hadoop:3.2)

### For HDFS

[core-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml):

```xml
<property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000</value></property>
```

Code (default path is on hdfs storage):

```py
df.writeStream.format("kafka").option("checkpointLocation", '/tmp/checkpoint').start()
```

### For file

[core-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml):

```xml
<property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>file:///</value></property>
```

Code (default path is on file storage):

```py
df.writeStream.format("kafka").option("checkpointLocation", '/tmp/checkpoint').start()
```

### Change storage in code

Code (Unimportant to default value):

```py
df.writeStream.format("kafka").option("checkpointLocation", 'hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/tmp/checkpoint').start()

# or

df.writeStream.format("kafka").option("checkpointLocation", 'file:///tmp/checkpoint').start()
```